# Implementation of method in class c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm new in oop and don't know how to specify this problem globally. I have two classes. Client

```
class Client
{
private:
    int code;
    string name;
public:
    Client(int c, string n);
    int getCode();
    string getName();
};

Client::Client(int c, string n)
{
    this->code = c;
    this->name = n;
}

int Client::getCode()
{
    return this->code;
}

string Client::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

and Account

```
class Account
{
private:
    int number;
    double balance;
    double interestRate;
    Client* owner;
  };
```

and I have method like this:

```
Client* Account::getOwner()
{
    return this->something;
}
```

Can you please tell me, how can I get client's code and name from this method?

Comment: this is very much a Java style

Comment: I'm just doing, what our teacher told us to do

Comment: get the code and the name?? you could just return `this->owner` and call `->getName()` and `->getCode()` on the returned pointer

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh when I do this, I get error for no suitable conversion from string to client

Comment: Well no-one can help with that if they can't see exactly what you wrote, and exactly what the error is: you need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KNfhmbTK

Comment: Is that minimal? It looks like you just dumped all your code without attempting to isolate the part that causes the problem. And it still doesn't show the error. And it should be edited into the question instead of pasted on an external site which will inevitable cause link rot.

Comment: You have to change the return type of the method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please tell me, how can I get client's code and name from this method?

The method is called `getOwner`. A method called `getOwner` should ... get ... the owner. Nothing else.

If you want to get the owner's *name*, either write a new method

```
string getOwnerName() const { return owner->getName(); }
```

or ...

(better because it reduces coupling between the Account and Client classes, possibly worse because it depends on exposing the owner directly, but then you're already doing that ...)

... just delegate this to the client code:

```
cout << account->getOwner()->getName();
```